# What does :where(:root) mean in SCSS

Tags: sass

I have an example code with `:where(:root)`

```
:where(:root) {
    //code
}
```

I know about `:root`, but not about `:where()`.

I can't find anything on google. What it does actually?

Comment: `:where` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) on mdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :where() CSS pseudo-class function takes a selector list as its argument, and selects any element that can be selected by one of the selectors in that list.

```css
/* Selects any paragraph inside a header, main
   or footer element that is being hovered */
:where(header, main, footer) p:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The above is equivalent to the following */
header p:hover,
main p:hover,
footer p:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

More info here:
[:where() Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where)

Comment: Good information, although I'm not sure it explains why one would use `:where(:root)`, as it seems as though it would be functionally equivalent to writing the clearer, more succinct selector of `:root`...

Comment: You would have to ask the person that wrote the CSS to know for sure. However IMO it doesn't make sense to do `:where(:root)` as you could just target the `:root` element directly (since only one selector is present in the pseudo-class function and it's not targeting any other element/selector). In fact I think it would be less performant to use the pseudo-class function. As shown in the example above, its just a clearer and more consolidated way to have a collection of selectors target another element/selector.